# Switching between 3G and WiFi on iPhone with Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, wifi, 3g

I have a native app built using MonoTouch that uses web services to communicate with a business layer.  I am trying to get some better behavior when the device switches between 3G and WiFi.  It seems that if the app starts with WiFi it must continue to run with WiFi and cannot switch to 3G and vice versa.  If I run the app under 3G I can initiate airplane mode to shut down the connection and engage Wifi and my app won't talk to the services.  If I am running Wifi first and then shut it down and engage 3G it won't talk to my services layer.

If I kill the app and launch it again it will work fine.  I can even engage Safari and hit the same services through the browser on the device to verify there is a route to get there, but my app still won't talk to the services until it is back on the original connection type.  I am not doing anything to hold onto connections.  Just opening and closing HttpWebRequests on demand.  The network reachability flags always indicate I have a route available.

The application is one where people walk out of a building connected to WiFi and may walk far enough they lose the WiFi and 3G engages.  It doesn't switch for some reason, which I don't understand as I thought it was supposed to happen automatically.

Comment: I don't think this is your app's fault.  When switching between 3G and Wifi like you mention, does Safari work?  You can try going to the same url in Safari that your webservice uses.

Comment: Yes, Safari works fine.  That is part of the reason I am confused.  The network reachability flags see a connection, I can get there via Safari, but for some reason the requests coming out of my app don't go through unless I switch back to the original connection type.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that the network to a particular site is up like this:

```
 MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.StartWWAN (new Uri ("http://www.google.com"));
```

Comment: I am using the network reachability flags to determine that I have a route to the host before attempting any calls.  using (var networkReachability = new NetworkReachability(hostName))...  My understanding is if I use StartWWAN that would try and wake up just the WiFi.  Is that correct?  It doesn't matter whether it is 3G or WiFi.  I am just trying to get either of them to work when it fails over and not having to restart my application.  Any additional advice is appreciated.

Comment: So it sounds like you are using a different URL for Wifi than on 3G, correct?  Can you just use the public URL always?  If that is the case, you won't have to think about switching over at all.